# Timeout on select query from external service after making an update on the same table

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

This is such a weird situation. I have Microsoft SQL Server database, app written in java (queries run using javax.persistence.Query) and external service written in C#.

I have a procedure that makes update on table MyTable.
There are only two update statements in this procedure:

```
UPDATE
    MyTable
SET
    status = dbo.getStat(id)
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        ...
    )

UPDATE
    MyTable
SET
    status = 3
WHERE
    status = 2 
    AND EXISTS
    (
        ...
    )
```

EXISTS part is the same for both statements.
In my java app I use following code to launch this procedure:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(recources.getString("updateStatuses"));
query.setHint("toplink.refresh", "true");
query.setParameter(1, sessId);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Under updateStatuses I have following sql:

```
EXEC updateStatusesP ?
```

After that I select records from this table if they have status equal to 3:

```
SELECT 
    id 
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE 
    status = 3
    AND EXISTS
    (
        ...
    )
```

I iterate through ids and I make a call to external service written in C# which modifies data in db.

The thing is that currently I'm getting a timeout on a select query launched from this external service. It's a query selecting data from MyTable.

If I remove first update statement from my updateStatusesP procedure then it works fine (no timeout). If I modify first query to include "status = " condition in WHERE clause then it also works fine. But without it I get this timeout.

There is a trigger and index on this table. I removed them to check if maybe there is something happening there. No changes.

If I make a direct call to this external service (via postman) then I get correct response. Only when calling it from application code: procedure, select query to select ids and then call to external service - I'm getting a response from this service (with info about timeout) and I can see in db monitoring tool that it didn't go pass first select query launched inside this service.

I don't understand what is happening. I tried putting those updates into transaction and committing it at the end of the procedure but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check out the *execution plain*? I suspect the problem can be the function `getStat`, what does it do?

Comment: It calculates status based on other columns from the same table. But when I changed body of this function to simple "return 3" I still got timeout. This procedure launched on db (not from application code)  takes no time.

Comment: Now that I checked again it's about this "status = 2" condition in WHERE clause. If I add it to the first query (but then I'm not going to end up with a query I want) everything works fine. When I remove it from the first query I get timeout on select query in this external service.