# Committing transaction with update statement before making a call to external service

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, transactions

Yesterday I've asked a question: [Timeout on select query from external service after making an update on the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369048/timeout-on-select-query-from-external-service-after-making-an-update-on-the-same) but I'm starting new conversation about the same problem because I investigated it more and now it turned out to be a bit different problem than I previously thought.

[image]

This is a picture from database monitoring tool after I used a function from my application. Those three green queries are started from my java application and they are:

1. procedure with select query
2. procedure with two update queries on MyTable
3. select query on MyTable

then there is a call to external service which makes select query on MyTable (red one). This query times out (because it can't read from MyTable). I don't know why. I tried modyfing this second procedure with update queries to have those updates committed before making a call to external service. I tried:

1. putting only update queries inside a procedure

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE 
   ...
   AS
   BEGIN
       UPDATE
           ....

       UPDATE
           ....
   END
   ```
2. putting update queries into transaction and committing it inside this procedure
3. but only when I end procedure with:

   ```
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
   ```

without starting a transaction inside this procedure I'm not getting a timeout on (red) select query. But this seems like a terrible idea to commit transaction which I don't know where was started.

Any ideas what I can do about it or how to investigate this problem? Basically I stuck here and don't know what to do next.

Comment: @@TRANCOUNT is > 0 because of the "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON" at the beginning of your monitoring log.